# AChartEngine current position

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using AChartengine for some android application, how can i update X and Y description when someone scroll graph at runtime?

For example, i want to update X axis description is X value in less then 10 to Low, but if X value is between 10 and 20 to set description value to medium.

I want to know what is current view point at graph.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a pan listener on your GraphicalView reference and changing the custom labels when notified about pan events.